# Oracle DBMS Scheduler Email Notifications Dynamically Send Server and Instance Name

Tags: oracle, jobs, event-notification

We have two Oracle database servers. One for production with one instance on it, and another one with multiple instances for Dev, Test, etc. I have some jobs that run on production and email me when they fail. I had originally set the sender to be something like server1.prod@company.com, so that I knew what environment the error was coming from.

Problem is when we copy production to one of the test or dev environments to get them up to date, then the job errors out for whatever reason, but it says it is coming from server1.prod@company.com which is incorrect.

I would like the notification email to pick up the servername and instance name that it is sent from, so if it comes from test it would be server2.test@company.com. If that is not possible, then it would be fine to get this info in the subject line or body of the email.

I can get the server and instance name pretty easy with

```
SELECT  host_name, instance_name
FROM    v$instance;
```

,but I can't figure out how to get this to be used in the job email notifications.

I set these jobs up using the sql developer wizard, so if you can show me how to change it with that would be fine, or with pl/sql code, I am ok with either.

If none of this is possible, then is there I way I can make the jobs to not send out once they get to the non production environments at least because I really don't care if they fail there.

Comment: How are you sending the emails?

Comment: DBMS_SCHEDULER.add_job_email_notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SYS_CONTEXT can be used to extract the host name of the database server and the instance name.

You simply call `dbms_scheduler.add_job_email_notification` in order to add the email notification like the following:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.add_job_email_notification (
  job_name => <JOBNAME>,
  recipients => <EMAIL>,
  subject => 
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') || ' ' || 
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME') ||
    ' - Scheduler Job Notification-%job_owner%.%job_name%-%event_type%', 
  events => 'job_failed');
END;
```

The 12c documention for all of the SYS_CONTEXT parameters can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF06117).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, that did it. Was able to use that to generate the send from address I wanted. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

when setting up job_notifications DO NOT set a value for the sender.  instead set the scheduler attribute email_sender for your db.

the default email_sender will be the value provided for the email_sender as shown below.
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_SCHEDULER_ATTRIBUTE('email_sender','Oracle_Job_Scheduler_ENVXXX@provider.com');

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of dynamically obtaining server and instance names at run time.